# Remote Desktop AVC 444 Hardware Encoding with Super Ultrawide Display

Tags: remote-desktop, h.264

As my daily driver workstation, I RDP from a Windows 10 desktop to a Windows 10 VM with a GTX 1080 passed through. I just upgraded my monitor from 3440x1440 to 5120x1440. I noticed recently that the video playback experience was a little off. This lead to some digging, in which I discovered that AVC 444 + H264 hardware encoding feature on the server was not working. The server is under the impression that my client does not support hardware accelerated decoding, but it definitely does. If I drop the resolution on the client machine to 3440x1440, AVC starts working again.

What is this a limitation of? Is this the NVENC encoder on the GPU? Or Microsoft's implementation of hardware encoding for Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Remote Desktop protocol restricts the max resolution at which it does AVC to HEVC level 5.1 (as defined here: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding_tiers_and_levels)). Therefore, it restricts the maximum individual frame size to 4096px for each dimension and 9437184px for total frame size.

This correlates to what you are seeing - you are crossing the 4096px threshold and then AVC no longer works.